# fetching the data from a csv file with a range of date

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am making a program where I want to extract the data from a csv file with the range of date (like +-14 days from a specific date)...ofcourse there is a column in the csv file with the dates.

Comment: You need to provide what you tired to achieve that with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a few things:

You could use

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, nrows = x)
```

Where x is the number of rows you want

Or use a one line command:

```
df = df[14:28]
```

The 14 and 28 can be whatever slice size you want.

Hope this helps

Comment: crest_day = river_data[(river_data['Date'] > '2016-8-1') & (river_data['Date'] <= '2016-8-30')]

Comment: this has worked but I am getting index along with my first column and don't know how to call that in if condition

Comment: @Sanjeev I am not quite clear with what your are saying